# pdfbox showText width and height setting

Tags: fabricjs, pdfbox

I am creating web based app where you annotate a pdf at browser(using pdf.js and fabricjs) and save the annotations at server side (java servlet REST endpoint) using Apache pdfbox (2.0.x). I can overlay images and text using PDPageContentStream's drawImage and showText methods. Also the user may scale the annotations at browser by selecting and dragging it at corners. This is properly scaled for drawImage by adjusting the width parameter based on the scaleX factor set by fabricjs. But for showText I cannot find any options to scale the text. I can adjust the font size, but that won't translate correctly against the corner.

Any thoughts on how to scale (or change height and width) and put a text on pdf using showText method of PDPageContentStream

Thanks in advance 
Prem

```
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(doc, page, AppendMode.APPEND, true, true);

            scaleX = signObj.get("scaleX").getAsFloat();
            scaleY = signObj.get("scaleY").getAsFloat();

            annoType = signObjWrapper.get("annoType").getAsInt();
            float x_adjusted = (signObj.get("left").getAsFloat()) + page.getCropBox().getLowerLeftX();
            float y_adjusted = -(signObj.get("top").getAsFloat()) + page.getCropBox().getUpperRightY();

            if (annoType == SIGN) // this annotation is a sign object
            {
                contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, x_adjusted,
                        y_adjusted - (signObj.get("height").getAsFloat() * scaleY),
                        signObj.get("width").getAsFloat() * scaleX, signObj.get("height").getAsFloat() * scaleY);
                contentStream.close();
            } else if (annoType == TEXT) {
                //Begin the Content stream 
                contentStream.beginText();
                //Setting the font to the Content stream 
                contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.COURIER,signObj.get("fontSize").getAsInt());
                //Setting the position for the line 
                contentStream.newLineAtOffset(x_adjusted, y_adjusted - (signObj.get("height").getAsFloat() * scaleY));
                //Adding text in the form of string 
                contentStream.showText(signObj.get("text").getAsString());
                //Ending the content stream
                contentStream.endText();
                //Closing the content stream
                contentStream.close();
            }
```

Comment: If you tag a question as an iText question, you should make that question about iText, not about PdfBox!

Comment: thanks removed iText

Comment: I guess I can use setTextMatrix to do scaling!. pdfbox experts please comment ! Even if I can use setTextMatrix how to map scaleX and scaleY to setTextMatrix !?

Comment: try `setTextMatrix(Matrix.getScaleInstance(scaleX, scaleY));`

Comment: Did my comment help or not?